# Listening for clicks on a disabled AlertDialog-Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-dialog

I want to listen for clicks on the `positive` button of an `AlertDialog`, which I have disabled by calling `button.setEnabled(false);`.

How should I do this? If this is not possible, is there a known workaround?

PS. The reason I want to do this, is that I want to show a toast when somebody hits the button, saying "You need to do this before you can continue".

Comment: Why don't you hide the button from view until a user completes a certain task?

Comment: That is an option, but this just makes the dialog less understandable, while I want to make it more understandable (with the hint in the toast). Your suggestion is just equal to what I've got at the moment (hiding vs. disabling).

Comment: I am not very sure about listening for clicks when the button is disabled; so I suppose you can just show a toast if the user has not completed the task and just don't disable the button.

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion actually. Do you know anything about changing the buttons text color, so it looks disabled? I know about regular buttons, but not sure about AlertDialog buttons.

Comment: I actually think you could blurr the button using some matrix; I could give code to blur something but now the issue is that I am not sure about the built-in button. You can create your own button too in your custom view then apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a way to listen for clicks on a disabled button. This is a workaround.

I liked the result I got by changing the color of the button, making it look like it's disabled.

What you want to do:

```
// Instantiate positive button
  final Button posButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

// Save the original button's background
  final Drawable bg = posButton.getBackground();

// Set button's looks based on boolean
  if (buttonDisabled) {
      posButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.disabledButtonColor, null));
         // R.color.disabledButtonColor == #DBDBDB, which is pretty close to 
         //    the color a disabled button gets.
      posButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         // Color.TRANSPARENT makes sure all effects the button usually shows disappear.
  } else {
      posButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, null));
         // R.color.colorPrimaryDark is the color that gets used all around my app.
         //    It was the closest to the original for me.
      posButton.setBackground(bg);
         // bg is the background we got from the original button before.
         //    Setting it here also re-instates the effects the button should have.
  }
```

Now, don't forget to catch your buttons actions whenever it's "disabled"

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (buttonDisabled) {
        // Button is clicked while it's disabled
    } else {
        // Button is clicked while it's enabled, like normal
    }
}
```

That should do, have fun with it.